# Eclipse popup dialog lacks info after attaching android sources

Tags: android, eclipse, ide, javadoc, content-assist

When I type some class method, Eclipse* brings up a **dialog with completion suggestions**, and when one of those is selected, it will display another dialog showing the method **prototype** (returned value, parameters, etc), method description, as well as an indication of whether the method is deprecated and at what **API level** it was added/deprecated.

**But after I attach the android sources, I no longer get in this dialog the prototype nor the API indications.**

**Is there anyway I can get these indications along with attached sources at the same time?** It's really annoying and time consuming having to detach and reattach sources all the time for this purpose, or searching in the web browser for that matter.

**Edit:** I attached sources in this way: Right-click on project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Android 4.2->android.jar->Source attachment->Edit->External location->External Folder->"C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk/sources". Api 17 sources are in there. Is something wrong in my approach?

Regards

--
*Eclipse for Mobile Developers
Version: Juno Service Release 1
Build id: 20121004-1855

Tried as well in:
Eclipse SDK
Version: 4.2.1
Build id: M20120914-1800

Comment: I've never used Eclipse for Mobile Developers. I use the standard (Classic?) eclipse and I don't have this problem. It's not an answer as to how to fix your setup but if it really inconveniences you, I recommend switching eclipse versions.

Comment: I shall try the standard version ASAP (can't for the moment), and will get back to you. Thank you. Maybe this is just a bug.

Comment: @Squonk Unfortunately I don't have the time to try this out yet, but please make your comment an answer so I can award the rep pts to you. Thank you. When I have the chance to try I'll post back.

Comment: Tried. Still no luck. I downloaded Eclipse Classic, installed ADT, created new android project and attached sources as explained in my question (see new edit).

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new workspace in eclipse and attach the sources once to the project target api - not the minimum sdk version .

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I created a new workspace, then a new project, minimum api was 8, target api is 17. Checked that content-assist was working perfectly, attached sources and afterwards it was showing the aforementioned problem. I attached sources in this way: Right-click on project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Android 4.2->android.jar->Source attachment->Edit->External location->External Folder->"C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk/sources". Api 17 sources are in there. Is something wrong in my approach? Maybe this is a bug with my Eclipse version?

Comment: @KevinRemo : I'm wondering if this is because your minimum API is 8 but you're attaching the source for 17. Try setting the minimum and target API as 17 and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I've tried several things: New project with both minimum and target API set to 17, another project set to 15, removed both sources subfolders out of the sources folder, one at a time. Tried all conceivable permutations I could think of. Always the same effect. And my conclusion is that something is terribly wrong either with the Eclipse versions I downloaded or with the android sources I downloaded. I hope if more people is having the same problem we'll eventually find a solution. Nonetheless I'd prefer to award you the rep. pts. now for your continued effort rather than losing them for good.

Comment: @Squonk, all right, I just realized my mistake. I awarded MaTriXy because I thought the previous comment was from him instead of yours. I'm sorry pal, I wish you had made your comment an answer.

Comment: @KevinRemo : No problems. Life is quite busy for me at the moment and I'm just dipping in and out of stackoverflow. There may well be a bug in eclipse - I had one situation yesterday when experimenting where it refused to let me attach the sources. It went through the motions and let me select a source folder but each time I went back, it said "Not attached" (or something similar). If I come across anything that solves your problem I'll let you know. At least the points went to somebody and weren't wasted. Good luck.